# Javascript reference local file in Windows Phone WebBrowser

Tags: javascript, html, windows, windows-phone-8, pdftron

I am trying to display a document using the PDFTron javascript library, on Windows Phone 8.

To achieve this, I must solve 2 problems:

1. I must be able to reference a file locally on disk, on the device.
2. I must be able to load the PDFTron javascript library

To ensure I have solved (1.), I used a  tag like this, which works fine:

```
<img src="C:\Data\Users\DefApps\AppData\{F6F933BE-1AD8-4B8D-AD14-89718F6E4EE1}\local\c3195b53-45d5-4bdf-9c5d-44812fd1bdcb">
```

To ensure I have solved (2.), I used the PDFTron library to show a document from the web:

```
$(function() {
    var viewerElement = document.getElementById('viewer');
    var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
        documentType: "xod",
        path: "Assets/webviewer/lib",
        initialDoc: "http://somedocument.xod",
    }, viewerElement);
});
```

Which works fine. However, I want to display a document from disk. It seems like i should be able to use a similar approach, as I used with the  tag, however, the following does not work:

```
$(function() {
    var viewerElement = document.getElementById('viewer');
    var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
        documentType: "xod",
        path: "Assets/webviewer/lib",
        initialDoc: "C:\Data\Users\DefApps\AppData\{F6F933BE-1AD8-4B8D-AD14-89718F6E4EE1}\local\ee15ebaa-064c-4572-a828-f189c009ffe4",
    }, viewerElement);
});
```

Is there something about javascript syntax Im not aware of? Perhaps using a path with "{" and "}" is a problem? I have tried escaping them, with no luck.

The same html and javascript (using a different path, obviously) works as expected on iOS and Android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried running the WinRT sample project that comes with the WebViewer SDK?
\WebViewerJS\samples\winrt

Answer (score 0):

Windows Store Apps are very restrictive on file access. This link describes the folders to which you have access to in a windows store app.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx

Generally, to get access to anything else, the OS file picker window has to be used.

So to get access to `C:\Data\Users\DefApps\AppData\{F6F933BE-1AD8-4B8D-AD14-89718F6E4EE1}\local\ee15ebaa-064c-4572-a828-f189c009ffe4` you probably need to launch the OS file picker.

Comment: I see. That doesn't explain why i *CAN* access the file when using an <img> tag, but *NOT* when passing it to PDFTron (files are in same location)... Unless there is some magic wrapper trickery giving <img> access, but not javascript?!